# Windows application Suddenly terminated

Tags: c#

Hi my windows application suddenly stops working and gives the error on Windows 7 OS.

"A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

Even the Error log is not written in My Error Log File.

I have try and Catch block to my each function..

Why??

Comment: Probably an unhandled exception. Try running your program in debug mode with a debugger attached.

Comment: Did it occur in the on Load event? Console app, winforms, etc.? Was it when a certain event was fired? Running with a debugger should pinpoint the error and then post the code around it.

Comment: @ jordanhill123 No. Process is ruuning for 3 hours and Suddenely got this exception even i had used try and catch block on each function.